# MSLinqToSQLGenerator warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

> WARNING:
>   A custom tool 'MSLinqToSQLGenerator' is associated with file 'MyApp\Forms\MyData.dbml', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

I've uploaded my code to Source Control and it compiles just great.  My co-worker downloaded the code and gets the above warning.  He tried right-clicking and running Custom Tool, but this did not resolve the warning. How can we trigger the generation and clear the warning?

Comment: Try making a tiny change e.g. renaming an identifier, saving, and then renaming it back.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.net c#: Linq-toSql:" nd such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by 'identifier'?

Comment: If it's a .dbml document then it'll be a database schema definition. By identifier I meant things like table names, column names, etc. - just anything that you can edit in Visual Studio that will register as a changed file so that the output gets regenerated. Or for example you could change a column from nullable to not-nullable.

Comment: I'm not sure about this solution since I'm working fine but my co-worker is getting the warning.

Answer (score 27):

You need to install the "LINQ to SQL tools" item under the "Code Tools" category in the "Individual Components" tab of the Visual Studio installer.

[image: LINQ to SQL tools]

Comment: Old post but this should be 100% the accepted answer, was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot!